# Implementing a Role Based Login with Menu in ASP.Net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi all this is the first time i am working on an MVC application,can any one provide me some ideas it will be greatfull...i have to develop a page where 
How can I implement role based login to users with the menu assigned to them in asp.net MVC 3. Consider I have three table UserInfo(UserId, UserName, Password,RoleId,MenuID) and Role(RoleId, RoleName).,Menu (MenuID,MenuName).

I want to validate user from Database(UserInfo Table) and also want to retrieve roles from that table. And want to use like ,how i ahve to design my project and controllers,views and models

Need your help and idea....

Answer (score 0):

you can use .net login control for log in and manage the roles.
Open your application in VS2010 then go to to Project menu then open the ASP.Net Configuration, and add roles as per you need.

```
Roles.IsUserInRole("RoleName")
```

like this you will check the logged in user role and change your menu setting.

Hopefully this is helpfull for you.